# Hello there! I have Elementary OS. I'm struggling with this github project https://github.com/hsbalar/batcave

Tags: angular

I have Elementary OS.
I'm struggling with this github project https://github.com/hsbalar/batcave

So, I followed:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hsbalar/batcave
$ cd batcave
$ npm install
$ typings install
this last command gave me "typings command not found"
```

Then... I downloaded this Batcave-win32-ia32.tar.gz
 de aici https://github.com/hsbalar/batcave/releases
I unzipped it.

I followed this https://superuser.com/questions/904001/how-to-install-tar-xz-file-in-ubuntu

```
tar xf [filename]

./configure
make
sudo make install
```

I don't have any readme.md file
Neither ./configure works.

Then, I went down in that unzipped folder, in /home/dan/Downloads/batcave/resources/app/ , there I found the file 'typings'

So...I used

```
$ typings install
$ npm run build

$ npm start
```

But how to open it? I installed something from the web, but unsuccesfully.
On http://localhost:8080 shows me Unable to display this website

I just want to run the program in angular. Oh, I don't have github installed yet, but it doesn't say I need it.

Comment: Do you have any output in your webbrowser console ?

Comment: Do you mean in developers tools? Or where should I look exactly?

Comment: yep in the developer tools. Do you have any message ?